# Storing data returned from a database query into a on the fly created generic Go data type

Tags: go

Instead of using a `struct`, which is predefined in terms of its number of data fileds, capacity, and types of that fields, having a `map`, which is expandable and can contain several data types as value, will be more advantageous. For example, on database side, changes to column names, column types, or number of columns in a table will not affect the go code related to querying the database, such as go data structure you put the `rows` returned form your database query.

Is there a way in golang sql package or related drivers to know the types of the data, in rows, returned by a database query to define a `struct` with  appropriate number of fields and types?

If not how can a `map` be used to accomplish this with column names of returned `rows` are **keys** and row fields are **values** of this `map`?

Comment: Maybe you need some `go ORM's`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you'll have to use a map with values of type `interface{}` so they can store any type. If you also need the column names you'd have to use `rows.Columns()` to then extract all the data and types.

This will read all columns from a table and store the values in a map as type `interface{}` with the column names as keys. Based on that you should be able to work out what you need for your use.

```
var myMap = make(map[string]interface{})
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM myTable")
defer rows.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
colNames, err := rows.Columns()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
cols := make([]interface{}, len(colNames))
colPtrs := make([]interface{}, len(colNames))
for i := 0; i < len(colNames); i++ {
    colPtrs[i] = &cols[i]
}
for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(colPtrs...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for i, col := range cols {
        myMap[colNames[i]] = col
    }
    // Do something with the map
    for key, val := range myMap {
        fmt.Println("Key:", key, "Value Type:", reflect.TypeOf(val))
    }
}
```

Using the reflect package you can then get the Type for each column as needed as demonstrated with the loop at the end. Or you can use a [type switch](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) to extract the types.

The above is generic and will work with any number of columns and types.

Comment: will this generic approach is there any performance overhead as compared to the more static approach involving a struct for each table or query?

Comment: Definitely. If you use a struct or variables and thus know your types and columns most of the code from the generic approach is unnecessary, i.e. overhead to the direct approach. So in most cases you'd want to use variables or structs to select known data. But there are situations where a generic approach comes in very handy. I use it for example to publish entire tables from one database to another remote database and don't have to worry about the table structure or changes to it.

Comment: More on types: I think the map at this state of the above snippet, after populated, is ready to use in application logic with the data with correct types in it. I mean no type conversion is necessary, the types of data from populated into the map is same as the those in the database; integers of db are now go integers, strings of db are go strings all in their corresponding value places in that map, myMap.

Comment: Problem I now face with is one same row is appended to the slice I want rows to be gathered.

Comment: I have pointed out this in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569005/reading-database-rows-into-map-and-appending-to-a-slice-of-maps